# Not finding <?php use_javascripts_for_form($search_form) ?>

Tags: php, javascript, symfony1

I have this line right at the top of my .php file

```
<?php use_stylesheets_for_form($search_form) ?>
<?php use_javascripts_for_form($search_form) ?>
<div id='div_longgray_gradient2'>
<div id='div_float_img'>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function getMessages()
   {
       //do stuff here 
   }
</script>
//some html and php then:
<span class='spn_med_black_rbc' id='new_messages'>You have <?php 
  echo $new_mail_cnt = '<script type="text/javascript">getMessages(); return false;</script>';
</span>
```

but when I `grep -r "use_javascripts_for_form(" *` it does not find it - is this a function? I need to find out where this is defined, because I call another JS function getMessages and it is not executing it.

When I inspect the element in Chrome I get an error stating that getMessages is not defined, so I assume it's got something to do with the second line at the top?

Comment: It's definitely not a built-in function.  If you don't find it in your application, you should also grep for it in your `include_path`

Comment: Looks like your site is built using [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org). I've retagged your post so that someone versed in Symfony might find this.

Comment: `getMessages()` is defined in the raw HTML on that page... are you sure you're calling it in the right scope? You're not trying to do `someObj.getMessages()`?

Comment: 1. yes i use symfony, thank you for re-tagging it! :) and i see it is a symfony thing aaaargh!!!

2. how do i grep for it in the include_path?? huh?

3. i call: echo $new_mail_cnt = '<script type="text/javascript">getMessages(); return false;</script>';


yikes im struggling :(

Comment: 1. yes i use symfony, thank you for re-tagging it! :) and i see it is a symfony thing aaaargh!!! i have take it out! and all is still ok except i still get that getMessages is undefined???

2. how do i grep for it in the include_path?? huh?

3. i call: echo $new_mail_cnt = '<script type="text/javascript">getMessages(); return false;</script>';


yikes im struggling :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `use_javascripts_for_form` is defined in the asset helper, line 647: http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/helper/AssetHelper.php#L647

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about your question: you are looking for the file where the function use_javascripts_for_form is defined?

If yes: 
What happens if you leave out the ( from your grep statement (or put a \ before)? Possibly the ( is taken as a special character ...

the function "use_javascripts_for_form" is definitely not a PHP function, so it's defined somewhere in your PHP code/files ...

Comment: i get the same results when i grep -r "use_javascripts_for_form" *
i use symfony..let me google that quick :)